# Looping on each line and each position in python

Tags: python, loops, char

I'm stuck in a small looping problem.
I have a file with different positions.

```py
p = [10, 11, 16]
```

I have an input (have 5 line for example) file like this:

```py
s = """BCCDDDCDCCDDDDDDABCDABCABDBACBDCAACCBBCABACBCCABCACBCDCCCBDBACDCBBCBCBCCCACADAACCABABADBCBAABBBCCBB
BCCDDDCDCCDDDDDDABCDABCABDBACBDCAACCBBCABACBCCABCACBCDCCCBDBACDCBBCBCBCCCACADAACCABABADBCBAABBBCCBB
BCCDDDCDCCDDDDDDABCDABCABDBACBDCAACCBBCABACBCCABCACBCDCCCBDBACDCBBCBCBCCCACADAACCABABADBCBAABBBCCBB
BCCDDDCDCCDDDDDDABCDABCABDBACBDCAACCBBCABACBCCABCACBCDCCCBDBACDCBBCBCBCCCACADAACCABABADBCBAABBBCCBB
BCCDDDCDCCDDDDDDABCDABCABDBACBDCAACCBBCABACBCCABCACBCDCCCBDBACDCBBCBCBCCCACADAACCABABADBCBAABBBCCBB"""
```

Now I like to make a loop in python which will print only those positions given in `p` from each line in `s`.

The desired output will be:

```
DDA
DDA
DDA
DDA
DDA
```

Now, this is my code:

```py
p=np.loadtxt('positions')
s=np.loadtxt('s')
for i in range (0, len(s)): 
    for i in p:  
        print(line [int(i)], end='')
```

output is : `DDADDADDADDADDA`

How do I convert this output to:

```
DDA
DDA
DDA
DDA
DDA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to print each iteration in seperate line, then just use print statement like this

```
print(line [int(i)], end='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried that but it does not give me the desired output.

Comment: You can try the print('',end='/n') on the outer loop as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
p=np.loadtxt('positions')
s=np.loadtxt('s')
for i in range (0, len(s)): 
    for i in p:  
        print(line [int(i)], end='')
    print()
```

this way you add a linebreak at the end of the outer for-loop